# What to use instead UNION?

Tags: sybase

I have a query that are using UNION, but it works slow.

```
Select col1, col2 From table_1 (INDEX idx MRU)
  where (condition)
UNION
Select col1,col2 From table 2(INDEX idx MEU)
  where (condition)
```

how can I make it work faster?

Comment: Does the `UNION` perform slower that running the two individual queries consecutively?

Answer (score 0):

Um, it depends on how big the tables are, how selective the 'where' clauses are, etc.

You might try doing a "set showplan on" and then run your query which will give you output from the query optimizer.  Understanding the showplan output can be non-trivial though.   Also, make sure you've run "update statistics" on the tables to help the query optimizer make good decisions.

One note, the union operator implicitly performs a distinct operation.  That means you'll be sorting the results in tempdb.   If you don't care about duplicates, use "union all" instead.

Ben